# Haskell Memoization Codewars Number of trailing zeros of factorial n

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming, factorial

I am trying to solve the Codewars problem called: Number of trailing zeros of N! with Haskell. 
I know that I don't need to calculate the factorial to know the trailing zeros and in fact I am just counting how many many numbers are divisible by 5 and how many times for each.
I have written 2 version, one that uses memoization when defactoring a number in order to get how many times is divisible by 5 and another one that do not use memoization. 
What surprise me is that the supposed DP approach takes longer than the trivial recursive one. I am probably doing something very stupid in my code.

These are the functions:

```
zeros x = helperZeros [1..x]
helperZeros :: [Integer] -> Integer
helperZeros  = sumArrayTuple . filter (\x -> x `mod` 5 == 0)
sumArrayTuple = foldl (\acc x -> acc + (fastDef x)) 0
data Tree a = Tree (Tree a) a (Tree a)
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Tree l m r) = Tree (fmap f l) (f m) (fmap f r)
index :: Tree Integer -> Integer -> Integer
index (Tree _ m _) 0 = m
index (Tree l _ r) n = case (n-1) `divMod` 2 of
  (q,0) -> index l q
  (q,1) -> index r q
nats = go 0 1
  where
    go n s = Tree (go l s') n (go r s' )
      where
        l = n + s
        r = l + s
        s' = s * 2
fastDef:: Integer -> Integer
fastDef x = trace (show x) index memTreetDef x
memTreetDef = fmap (defact fastDef) nats
defact f n
  | n `mod` 5 /= 0 = 0
  | otherwise =  1 + f (n `div` 5)



zeros' x = helperZeros' [1..x]
helperZeros' :: [Integer] -> Integer
helperZeros'  = sumArrayTuple' . filter (\x -> x `mod` 5 == 0)
sumArrayTuple' = foldl (\acc x -> acc + (def x)) 0
def n
  | n `mod` 5 /= 0 = 0
  | otherwise = 1 + def (n `div` 5)
```

What I am trying to memoize is the result of the defact function, for example if I have already calculate defact 200, then it would reuse this result to calculate defact 1000.

I am fairly new to DP in Haskell.

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to count the number of twos?

Comment: @Bergi you always have enough twos to match all the fives!

Answer (score 1):

If you are tested your code performance with `trace` and `show` here, that is the issue: they are very slow compared to the main code. If not, performance of variants must be about the same.

The `def` function is a poor candidate for memoization. The average depth of recursion is not very different from `1`. The rest of the complexity is reduced to the operation `mod`, that is, the division that is hardly more expensive than table look up (and division by constant can be optimized to multiplication).